# Why is there no set of expected conditions for these languages?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I read that:

> Expected Conditions There are some common conditions that are
>   frequently encountered when automating web browsers. The Java, C#, and
>   Python bindings include convienence methods so you don’t have to code
>   an ExpectedCondition class yourself or create your own utility package
>   for them.

Source-http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Why are there no Expected conditions for ruby, javascript etc. ? How can I wait for conditions to be true in the missed languages ?

Comment: My guess that Python, java and C# have enough support so someone volunteered to write those classes. Ruby and Javascript did not found volunteers yet. It is free software, you can do it too (write your classes)  if you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java binding just sits in a sleep loop.  `WebDriverWait` is just a specialization of `FluentWait`.  [Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java#L233) is the implementation of `FluentWait.until`; as you can see, it just sits in a loop, sleeping and checking a condition, until either the condition is satisfied or the timeout period passes.  I imagine the C# and Python bindings do the same thing.  There is no OS-level system call to block until something happens in the browser.

You can do the same sleep loop thing in Ruby.  Javascript running on a browser is a different deal because there is no sleep method.